# ADF push json data to SQL

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have an adf pipeline to fetch data from API and store it to blob storage as json. Next I fetch the same json data from blob using lookup. Using foreach and filter I get some particular content inside the json filtered. Now I need to insert this filtered data to DB. Is there a way to copy the filtered data to DB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Update:

It is the same process if we input json array. As follows show:
[image]

My input is `[{\"customerId\":100001,\"cutomerName\":\"Tom\"},{\"customerId\":100002,\"cutomerName\":\"John\"},{\"customerId\":100003,\"cutomerName\":\"Tinny\"}]`, I can see 3 records in my Azure SQL.
[image]

---

Here I'm using Lookup activity to get one json object and copy it into azure SQL via Stored procedure activity.

1. This is my json type output of my lookup activity.

```
    "firstRow": {
        "customerId": 100001,
        "cutomerName": "Tom"
    }
```

[image]

2. In azure sql, we can create a table and a stored procudure.

```sql
--1. create table
create table dbo.CustomerInfo(
customerId INT,
cutomerName varchar(50)
)

--2. create stored procedure
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspCustomerInfo] @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS 
begin
    INSERT INTO dbo.CustomerInfo(customerId,cutomerName) 
        SELECT customerId,cutomerName
        FROM OPENJSON(@json,N'$')
            WITH (
            customerId INT N'$.customerId',
            cutomerName VARCHAR(255) N'$.cutomerName'
            );
end
```

3. In stored procedure activity setting, we should convert json to string via `@string(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow)`.
   [image]
4. This is my input of the stored procedure activity.
   [image]
5. This is my debug result:
   [image]
6. If you are facing more complex json object you can refer this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks It worked. 
I have one query here is even though what i wanted is success, in total this activity fails with error "The specified Stored Procedure is not valid. It could be caused by that the stored procedure doesn't return any data". Can you help me to avoid this and make this activity a success.

Comment: How should we handle if I have something like this with multiple objects: 
  [ {
        "customerId": 100001,
        "cutomerName": "Tom"
    },
  {    "customerId": 100002,
        "cutomerName": "Tom1"
   }]

Comment: Hi @ARUN VARRIAR. It is the same process if we input json array.  I've updated my answer. Did you solved the problem `The specified Stored Procedure is not valid...`? Are you using Stored procedure activity? Or you can post this issue.

Comment: Error: 
Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=SqlInvalidDbStoredProcedure,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The specified Stored Procedure is not valid. It could be caused by that the stored procedure doesn't return any data. Invalid Stored Procedure script: '[dbo].[TestProc]'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary. 

Also not sure, when I give raw json the above steps works perfectly. But when i give 
@string(activity('Filter1').output.value), it copies only the first row values

Comment: Hi @joseph xu I have resolved all other issues. But still not able to resolve this: Error: Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=SqlInvalidDbStoredProcedure,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The specified Stored Procedure is not valid. It could be caused by that the stored procedure doesn't return any data. Invalid Stored Procedure script: '[dbo].[TestProc]'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary

Comment: If you despise the JSON parsing ability of ADF please upvote this Azure Data Factory feedback idea: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/23432697-7026-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c